# My wordpress admin showing blank and my website not recognizing the style sheets

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

I have a website developed on a wamp server using the wordpress (current edition) themes. everything seem to work well while developing but upon transfer to a live domain via FTP into the public folder, the front end was not recognizing the style sheets and also accessing the admin page, i was able to login but the dashboard was appearing blank. is there any way out please? need i say that i have tried to disable the plugins by renaming the plugin folder, it still appear blank. i also put on the wp_debug, its still the same problem. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the wp-config.php file on your ftp.

Put the following at the beginning

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

where example.com hast to be replaced by your domain.

Comment: I still experience same problem